# Is there any significant overhead in using FragmentActivity over normal Activity in Android?

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

There isn't much to say here beyond title question.

There are some activities in my application that do not use `Fragments`, so I was wondering if there was any performance difference in using plain `Activity` in those cases, or should I just always go with `FragmentActivity` for the sake of consistency?

Comment: If there is a difference it's marginal at worst. Don't fall prey to premature optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't using any `FragmentActivity`-specific properties or methods, then it will just be nearly the same as a normal Activity (premature optimization). If you have finished programming the `FragmentActivity` and you are able to just switch to extending `Activity` instead, then you should change it to extend `Activity`, because if your app sells well and you want to add more features to it and later on you decide to change your normal `Activity` (but you extend it with `FragmentActivity`) to SomeOtherTypeActivity then most likely you will need to change your code somewhere else to fit the new implementation. But if you don't mind this, then staying with `FragmentActivity` shouldn't cause you performance hits.